# Drupal image keyword output in Alt Tag

Tags: drupal

I'm fairly new to Drupal and really only working on it for a client, but I've got a group of images I'm outputting into a list / gallery, however for a js I've written to do some nifty sorting and such, I need to have the keyword tags saved with the image to be output into the Alt field.

Is this a "replacement pattern" or even possible? Any resource links or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you getting the images into your list?

Comment: We definitely need more details on this: What are those 'keyword tags' and where do they come from (maybe taxonomy terms)? How is the list assembled (maybe views)? Where do the images come from ('standard' Drupal images, imagefield images, other ...)?

Comment: Ok, I poked around some more and the Keyword Field is getting generated by the Taxonomy module. The list is getting generated in a view of type "Node" ? Images are being uploaded as content (imagefield images).

Comment: So I found in the image view that there is something that is outputting all of the associated tags across Taxonomy vocabularies for a certain image : http://skitch.com/stuartlawder/dcdb7/screenshot
Any ideas on how I can spit that out in a normal page view?

Answer (score 3):

You can use tokens in imagefields if you enable the [imagefield_tokens](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens) module. The taxonomy terms should be available as replacement patterns on the field settings form under "ALT text settings" (the token you probably want is [term-raw]).

Comment: This could be an easy solution (+1). One caveat, though: The nodes term tokens only give *the first* (lightest) term of the node - if there are several terms associated with a node, the others won't be available through the tokens.

Comment: Henrik is right, I need to get all of the terms listed out, not just the first.